# How can I fix these errors when trying to run a ruby-based project on NetBeans 6.9.1?

Tags: ruby, netbeans, rails, gem

I am trying to run a ruby-based project on NetBeans 6.9.1 but nothing happens and Mongrel shows an error message.

```
ruby -v =>  1.8.7
rails -v => 2.3.8
gem -v => 1.5.0
```

Error message:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support.rb:56
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:1
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from script/server:3
```

When attempting the "`require 'thread'`" solution the error messages changes into this monster:

```
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#refresh! is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#refresh! called from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:34.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#load_gems_in is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#load_gems_in called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:322.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#initialize is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#initialize called from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:268:in `==': undefined method `name' for "actionmailer":String (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `==='
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `matching_specs'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `find_all'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:410:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:409:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `find_all'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `matching_specs'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:238:in `to_specs'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1208:in `gem'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:73:in `add_load_paths'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
        from /home/teste/sisgered/config/environment.rb:16
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from script/server:3
```

I have already tried downgrading/upgrading rubygems-update to 1.6.2, 1.5.3, and 2.6.12 with no changes, still nothing happens.

PS: I'm not allowed to change versions at whim, especially the OS (Ubuntu) and Ruby (1.8.7).

Comment: Excuse me, what are you trying to do? Do you mind placing that information somewhere in your question's body or title? That will give you better chances to get some support. Thank you!

Comment: Done. I'm not sure how be more specific, I'm not very good with English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix this issue by installing rubygems-update version **1.3.5**  and running the app **without** `require 'thread'` the other rubygems-update versions still don't work.